# How can I assign the contents of a geojson file to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

The code shown already works, but I want to clean it up. It declares a variable called **placez** which contains information in geojson format for the next part of the code to read and load on a map using filters. However, in reality, the amount of points to be mapped exceeds 50,000 (the example here only shows 2). What I want to know is how I can just load the data coming from a file in the same directory called **placesgj.geojson**, where the 50,000 data entries will be written in geojson format, to the variable **placez** instead of writing them manually there like in the example. The rest of the code is ommited for tidyness, and irrelevant for the functionality. Thanks in advance!

```
var placez = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "theatre"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "music"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.007481, 38.876516]
        }
    }]
};
map.on('load', function() {
    // Add a GeoJSON source containing place coordinates and information.
    map.addSource("placer", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": placez
    });
    placez.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        var symbol = feature.properties['icon'];
        var layerID = 'poi-' + symbol;
```

Comment: Why don't you just read your local file ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file Then parse it. Don't worry about the size of the string you'll get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to read the file.

```
function fetchJSON(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}
```

Assuming `placesgj.geojson` is in the same directory:

```
var data = fetchJSON('placesgj.geojson')
            .then(function(data) { 

        // do what you want to do with `data` here...
        data.features.forEach(function(feature) {
                console.log(feature);
                var symbol = feature.properties['icon'];
                console.log(symbol);
            });

});
```

Comment: Tried doing this but I couldn't get it to work. Kept getting an error message for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property forEach of undefined". Still works pasting the 50,000 lines of text though, so I guess I got that going for me. Will keep looking.

Comment: @FranciscoVG I've updated my answer, please check it out. Also make sure the geojson file is having  the right extension/type, and its path is passed correctly for the `fetchJSON` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of loading JSON file in to a javascript object. It can be done in Pure Java Script using XMLHttpRequest.

```
 function loadJSONFile(callback) {   

    var xmlobj = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");

    xmlobj.open('GET', 'placesgj.geojson', true); // Provide complete path to your json file here. Change true to false for synchronous loading.

    xmlobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlobj.readyState == 4 && xmlobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xmlobj.responseText);
          }
    };

    xmlobj.send(null);  
 }
```

call the loadJSONFile function by passing a call back function as below:

```
loadJSONFile(function(response) {
    var placez = JSON.parse(response);
 });
```

// Continue with your map.on('load', .. code here...

Comment: I'm getting an error message saying: "Uncaught ReferenceError: placez is not defined at...". The code works fine when copy-pasting the 50-lines of text content to the text editor, so I'll keep looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you can check the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

An example using [Leaflet API](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/examples/geojson/) to load a Layer:

```
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/basesEspaciales00/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=basesEspaciales00%3Aanimal2022ipa&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson')
  .then(response => response.json())
  //.then(data => console.log(data))
  .then (response => response)
  //.then (response => console.log (response))
  .then (response => mapa(response));
  
  function mapa(rta){
  var a = rta;
    var animalLayer = L.geoJSON(a, {

        filter: function (feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties) {
                // If the property "underConstruction" exists and is true, return false (don't render features under construction)
                return feature.properties.underConstruction !== undefined ? !feature.properties.underConstruction : true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
  }
```